# NebulaGraph database on AWS: Is there a way to fast deploy NebulaGraph database in my AWS virtual network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph-databases, nebula-graph

I have a experimental bot App in my AWS invironment, and I'd like to try to enhance it with a graph database. For now I located the open source graph database [NebulaGraph](https://www.nebula-graph.io/).
But it has a tool set with quite a few applications, and it is not so easy to install them all.

Is there a way to install a whole set of Nebula Graph cluster on AWS?

I tried to follow their [docs](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/) to install NebulaGraph database and its tools on my local machine, but now I want to install them on AWS and don't want to go through the whole process again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the quickstart of NebulaGraph on AWS [here](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-vesoft-nebula-graph-cloud/)

Comment: Or, I created a toy project for the fresh users named nebula-up: https://github.com/wey-gu/nebula-up to enable the oneliner command to bootstrap a containerized nebulagraph + toolings.

Comment: Thank you! The Quick Start Deployment Guide is perfect for solving my problem.